# How can I place a formula in a data property where another data property is used in protege 5.5.0?

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I would like to know if I can use a data property in another data property as a formula, here I leave the example I want to perform

Reputation = Initial perception (data property) * 0.20 + Travel confidence (data property) * 0.30

- experience history (previous data) * 0.50

The experience history is the data that was previously received from the reputation, I would also like to know how to obtain the data that was previously had in the ontology of that property data

Comment: use SWRL for this. But: the thing with the previous data will not work - OWL inference as well as SWRL reasoning is monotonic - you cannot invalidate existing facts, i.e. you can't "overwrite" the reputation value in your example. For things like this, a SPARQL 1.1 Update query or similar could be used.

Comment: @UninformedUser So to be able to carry out the formula, should I do it only through SPARQL update queries? reputation has been a data property as well as the other variables that affect the formula.
Is there another way to do this through an ontology?